# Why can't I build a Docker image containing both git and cmake?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to build a Docker image based on Ubuntu 20.04 that has both git and cmake. When I use the following Docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install git
#RUN apt-get -y install cmake
```

to create an image with only git, everything works:

```
$ docker build -t test1 .
DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
            Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:
            https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/

Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Step 1/3 : FROM ubuntu:20.04
 ---> bf40b7bc7a11
Step 2/3 : RUN apt-get -y update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a763dee7dff2
Step 3/3 : RUN apt-get -y install git
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 76dfdc96998a
Successfully built 76dfdc96998a
Successfully tagged test1:latest
```

When I use the following Docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get -y update
#RUN apt-get -y install git
RUN apt-get -y install cmake
```

to create an image with only cmake, everything works:

```
$ docker build -t test1 .
DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
            Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:
            https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/

Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Step 1/3 : FROM ubuntu:20.04
 ---> bf40b7bc7a11
Step 2/3 : RUN apt-get -y update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a763dee7dff2
Step 3/3 : RUN apt-get -y install cmake
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 35f12052da5c
Successfully built 35f12052da5c
Successfully tagged test1:latest
```

But, when I try to use the following Docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install git
RUN apt-get -y install cmake
```

to create an image with both git and cmake, I get some weird problem with tzdata (!?), that causes my terminal to freeze while seemingly waiting for an input (i.e. I try to input the desired info, but don't see any response)

```
$ docker build -t test1 .
DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
            Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:
            https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/

Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Step 1/4 : FROM ubuntu:20.04
 ---> bf40b7bc7a11
Step 2/4 : RUN apt-get -y update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a763dee7dff2
Step 3/4 : RUN apt-get -y install git
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 76dfdc96998a
Step 4/4 : RUN apt-get -y install cmake
 ---> Running in 728ea114cc68
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu cmake-data cpp cpp-9 gcc
  gcc-9 gcc-9-base libarchive13 libasan5 libatomic1 libbinutils libc-dev-bin
  libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcrypt-dev libctf-nobfd0 libctf0 libcurl4 libgcc-9-dev
  libgomp1 libicu66 libisl22 libitm1 libjsoncpp1 liblsan0 libmpc3 libmpfr6
  libquadmath0 librhash0 libtsan0 libubsan1 libuv1 libxml2 linux-libc-dev make
  manpages manpages-dev tzdata
Suggested packages:
  binutils-doc cmake-doc ninja-build cpp-doc gcc-9-locales gcc-multilib
  autoconf automake libtool flex bison gdb gcc-doc gcc-9-multilib gcc-9-doc
  lrzip glibc-doc make-doc man-browser
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu cmake cmake-data cpp
  cpp-9 gcc gcc-9 gcc-9-base libarchive13 libasan5 libatomic1 libbinutils
  libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcrypt-dev libctf-nobfd0 libctf0 libcurl4
  libgcc-9-dev libgomp1 libicu66 libisl22 libitm1 libjsoncpp1 liblsan0 libmpc3
  libmpfr6 libquadmath0 librhash0 libtsan0 libubsan1 libuv1 libxml2
  linux-libc-dev make manpages manpages-dev tzdata
.
.
.
Configuring tzdata
------------------

Please select the geographic area in which you live. Subsequent configuration
questions will narrow this down by presenting a list of cities, representing
the time zones in which they are located.

  1. Africa      4. Australia  7. Atlantic  10. Pacific  13. Etc
  2. America     5. Arctic     8. Europe    11. SystemV
  3. Antarctica  6. Asia       9. Indian    12. US
Geographic area:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @KamilCuk - Thx. It answers my practical need to build the image, but I still don't understand why I only get this problem when I try to include *both* git and cmake.

Comment: WHY: cmake depends on tzdata, whose installation requires selecting a timezone which is normally done interactively. The base image doesn't have perl-modules installed, so debconf falls back to a 'Teletype' method that detects no input is available (in a 'build' container) and uses a default. git depends on (installs) perl-modules so when after that you install tzdata, debconf finds and uses perl Term::ReadLine which apparently doesn't detect this, and hangs. This is probably a bug somewhere, but I don't have lots  of time to spend on it.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - Thx. I just verified by building the image & installing cmake first and then git. But, I'm going to rebuild using the defined time zone